# Objective C with Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a problem with a Objective-C class. I usually work with Swift, but in my job I'm working on Objective-C project. I want to combine a Swift class with Objective-C code base within single project.

In Swift I created a class this way:

```
@objc class MyView: UIView {
    init(frame: CGRect, title: String, color: UIColor) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        ...
    }
}
```

and I call it:

```
view = MyView(frame:frame, title:@"title",color:redColor)
```

But in Objective-C just I can call it with:

```
MyView *view = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect)];
```

I can't set the `title` and `color` parameters.
How I can set the parameters?

Comment: that objective-C statement is not valid. and you are missing the `@objc` to make your class even accessible to objective-c. So what exactly are you asking?

Comment: I have this in my code, but is the same

Comment: What is `(CGRect)` in `[[MyView alloc]initWithFrame:(CGRect)];`?

Comment: Post your actual code. lu2302 told you what was wrong with your code only to be told this isn't actually your code. Frustrating + off-putting.

Comment: The parameter by default of a frame

Comment: Did you do `#import "ModuleName-Swift.h"` in your `.m` file (where `ModuleName` should be replaced with the name of your module)? If you don't, it won't find that Swift method from Objective-C.

Comment: Your "code" is not code. Show only _actual_ code, and show only and exactly the actual code necessary and sufficient to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, #import "MyProject-Swift.h"

Comment: Then (a) do a build (to make sure that header is generated); and (b) command-click on that `#import` of the system generated header and take a look at it and see if you find `MyView` defined in there. If not, try cleaning ("Clean" from Xcode's "Product" menu) and rebuilding and taking another look. Also make sure that the Swift source file is included in the target's "Compile Sources" section on the "Build Phases" tab of the target settings.

Comment: To the OP: You provided incomplete information, plus code fragments that can't possibly compile. If you want help, provide a complete description of the problem, including the actual code you are using. Otherwise you're wasting everybody's time and annoying the people best qualified to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you do `#import "ModuleName-Swift.h"` in your `.m` file (where `ModuleName` should be replaced with the name of your module)? If you don't, it won't find that Swift method from Objective-C.

When I do that, your custom `init` method for `MyView` is now accessible via Objective-C:

```
MyView *myView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:frame title:@"title" color:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
```

See [Importing Swift into Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID157).